# Chrome, Firefox and Safari not applying XSLT? IE does!

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, xslt, safari

The below is returned to the browser:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="to_xhtml.xslt"?>
    <root>
      <value>test data</value>
    </root>
```

Chrome 7 and FF 5 do not appy the XSLT only showing the XML values. IE does apply the XSLT showing the resultant XHTML.

The XSLT file is there and is valid - I can proccess the XML locally and open the resulting XHTML in Chrome and Firefox...

The web server is IIS 6 and interface is PHP 5.3 if that has anything to with it?

**UPDATE:** XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output 
    method='xml' 
    indent='yes'
    doctype-public='"-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd"'/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </p>
    ...
  </html>
```

Comment: 1. What Content-Type is the initial file served as? 2. Show the xslt.

Comment: @meder 1. The default returned by php: text/html (from Live HTTP headers), im guessing it should be text/xml? 2. Top of XSLT above.

Comment: have you tried with  `method='html'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure your page is served with the correct HTTP **Content-Type** header value in this case: **text/xml**, possible in PHP using the header function:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xmlStr;
```

*thanks to meder who lead me in the right direction for this.

**Also** In Chrome and Safari an error still occurs while applying the XSLT because of the above doctype-public value:

```
<xsl:output 
method='xml' 
indent='yes'
doctype-public='"-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd"'/>;
```

It should be:

```
<xsl:output 
  method="xml"
  indent="yes"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd"/>
```

The doctype-public attribute should not even be looked at if doctype-system is not specfied according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method).

*thanks to LarsH for pointing out doctype-system should be in a separate value.

Comment: useful answer, +1. See also my answer regarding a correction for the value of doctype-public.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the **doctype-public** attribute: According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method),

> The doctype-public attribute should be
> ignored unless the doctype-system
> attribute is specified.

So something's pretty fishy about your `<xsl:output-method>` element, which has a doctype-public attribute but no doctype-system. (That doesn't excuse Chrome and Safari from "falling over" ... = crashing?)

Maybe you wanted

```
<xsl:output 
  method="xml"
  indent="yes"
  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd" />
```

See [here](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1027) for more about public and system identifiers in XML.

Apparently this is not the reason why Fx and Chrome wouldn't render your XML using XSLT (the content-type was the reason), but it's something you probably want to fix.

Comment: The reason Fx and Chrome wasnt rendering was the Content-Type, in addition (after Copntent-type was corrected) Chrome and Safari would fall over (stop applying the XSLT and display an error msg, displaying what XHTML had been produced so far - in this case nothing) applying the XSLT becuase of my first doctype-public value, inverting the apostrophes and quotes solved error. However as you have pointed out I should separate the doctype-system from the doctype-public value - thanks! I will update my answer.